# get bottomLeft & TopLeft corners

Tags: c++, opencv, objective-c++

---

I have a **point list** (`vector<cv::Point>`) like this:

```
[ 5, 10;
 15, 25;
 40, 30;
 10, 15]
```

I'd like to extract the 4 corners like...

- **top left corner**.       `cv::Point topLeft = cv::Point(5,10) ;`
- **top right corner**.      `cv::Point topRight = cv::Point(10,15) ;`
- **bottom left corner**.    `cv::Point bottomLeft = cv::Point(15,25) ;`
- **bottom right corner**.   `cv::Point bottomRight = cv::Point(40,30) ;`

> How can I get the 4 corners from the list using objc++?

---

**Note:** This is what I've tried so far but obviously it doesn't seems working.

```
cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(points);
cv::Point topLeft = rect.tl();
cv::Point bottomRight = rect.br();
cv::Point topRight = ??
cv::Point bottomLeft = ??
```

*I know that many questions have been asked on openCV & point vectors, but I hope someone is kind enough to give me a short answer to my question, as I am quite at a loss right now.*

**Edit**: `topLeft == minX & minY`, `topRight == maxX & minY`, `bottomLeft == minX & maxY`, `bottomRight == maxX & maxY`. This is how the corners are defined.

**Note**: The area will be a rectangle and it's not possible that two values are straight up like in a [diamond](http://www.coloringpages101.com/coloring-pages/Shapes/tn_new25_euszs.gif) (like @Jive mentioned).

Comment: Define "top left corner."  What if the points form a vertical diamond? http://www.coloringpages101.com/coloring-pages/Shapes/tn_new25_euszs.gif

Comment: So your right - but **the points will be part of a rectangle**. They are the **corner points** of a rectangle so `top-left` is the coordinate where the `x-value is minimum` and the `y-value` also is the `minimum`. @JiveDadson

Comment: you know, if you have top left (x1, y1) and bottom right (x2, y2) of rectangle, then chnaces are that top right is (x2, y1) and bottom left is (x1, y2)

Comment: And if two corners of the rectangle point straight up and down?

Comment: The will not be straight up and down `:)`

Comment: Okay then. Elaborate the constraints, and _then_ define "top left corner."

Comment: I've already done: `topLeft == minX & minY`, `topRight == maxX & minY`, `bottomLeft == minX & maxY`, `bottomRight == maxX & maxY`. @JiveDadson

Comment: @tempi Like you said, you've already done that. `topLeft.x == minX`, `topLeft.y == minY`, `bottomRight.x == maxX` and `bottomRight.y == maxY`. Then plug those in to the definitions of `TopRight` and `bottomLeft`. I'm not sure I understand what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Order 4 points in clockwise order, consider this following method.
This is referred from [this site](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/)

```
//   TL(1)-------TR(2)
//    |           |
//    |           |
//   BL(4)-------BR(3)
//
template<typename T>
int OrderPoints(vector<cv::Point_<T>>& ip_op_corners_orig)
{
    if (ip_op_corners_orig.size() < 4)
        return -1;

    //Making a copy of the Original corner points
    vector<cv::Point_<T>> corners = ip_op_corners_orig;

    ip_op_corners_orig.clear();
    ip_op_corners_orig.resize(4);

    //Sorting based on the X Co-ordinates of points
    vector<int> sIdx = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    vector<cv::Point_<T>> leftMost, rightMost;

    std::sort(sIdx.begin(), sIdx.end(), [&corners](int i1, int i2){return corners[i1].x < corners[i2].x; });

    //Getting the Left most and Right most points and getting the top left and bottom left points
    leftMost = { corners[sIdx[0]], corners[sIdx[1]] };

    //Getting the Top Left and Bottom Left point
    ip_op_corners_orig[0] = leftMost[0].y > leftMost[1].y ? leftMost[1] : leftMost[0];
    ip_op_corners_orig[3] = leftMost[0].y < leftMost[1].y ? leftMost[1] : leftMost[0];


    //Getting the Bottom right anfd top right point
    rightMost = { corners[sIdx[2]], corners[sIdx[3]] };

    //Getting the Top right and Bottom right point
    ip_op_corners_orig[1] = rightMost[0].y > rightMost[1].y ? rightMost[1] : rightMost[0];
    ip_op_corners_orig[2] = rightMost[0].y < rightMost[1].y ? rightMost[1] : rightMost[0];


    return 0;
}

//template explicit definitions
template int OrderPoints(vector<cv::Point>&);
template int OrderPoints(vector<cv::Point2d>&);
template int OrderPoints(vector<cv::Point2f>&);
```

**Edit 1:**
Since the points are already on the rectangle, then like @beaker mentioned, 
topLeft = minX & minY, bottomLeft = minX & maxY, topRight = maxX & minY, bottomRight = maxX & maxY.

Or you can define them like this

```
cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(points);
cv::Point topLeft = rect.tl();
cv::Point bottomRight = rect.br();
cv::Point bottomLeft = topLeft + cv::Point(0, rect.height);
cv::Point topRight = topLeft + cv::Point(rect.width, 0);
```

**Edit 2:**
Updated the code to work with all point types

Comment: Seems an awful lot of work when the orientation of the points is already given.

Comment: There are some issues in your code: What I got is `vector<cv::Point>` but your function takes `vector<cv::Point2f>`. How can I fix this?

Comment: replace cv::Point2f with cv::Point at all the places